# Unable to update Contact field on Candidate record

Tags: contact, master-detail

In my dev org, as part of an HR app, I've got a 'Candidate Test' object.
I added a 'Contact' master-detail relationship to link the candidate to an existing Contact.

I used a master-detail relationship instead of a lookup relationship so I can then use a roll-up summary on the Contact object and pull out records from the Candidate Test object such as the number of references, etc...

However, now, I can't update the Contact field on the Candidate Test record, even as a System admin.

Is there any way to make it possible?

I assume it's due to the fact that there's a master-detail relationship between the 2 objects but I'd like to be able to change the contact field on the candidate record.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have existing records on candidate object? if yes then create lookup relationship to contact and then populate lookup field values on candidate object. Once all existing records have lookup values then convert the relationship from lookup to master.

Comment: by default, children records cannot be reparented on a Master-Detail relationship, [as explained here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.relationships_considerations.htm&type=5): . `By default, records can’t be reparented in master-detail relationships. Administrators can, however, allow child records in master-detail relationships on custom objects to be reparented to different parent records by selecting the Allow reparenting option in the master-detail relationship definition.`

Comment: Thank you, @McCubo. I checked the box "Allow reparenting" on the Contact field of the Candidate object and now I can change the Contact. Thank you :-)